# where I can find materials for shoes?

Tags: materials

[image]could someone help me to find out from which websites I can download for free materials for shoes for Blender Cycles?

Many thanks in advance!

Cris

Comment: hello, maybe show what kind of texture you're trying to recreate so that someone propose a node setup for a procedural material

Comment: Related question: [Resources for Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15355/resources-for-blender)

Comment: many thx for answering to this topic, you could check when you have the time the image I attached!